# How do I include partials?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, velocity

I got this:

**main.vm**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> test </title>
</head>
<body>

$content

</body>
</html>
```

This should serve as the default template for all other views which are going to be included.

For example this one:

**example.vm**

```
#define($content)
<div>
<p> Hello World ! </p>
</div>

#end
```

How do I include that partial as content into the main.vm file?
Am I defining my templates right?

I couldn't figure out that from the official docs.

I'm using Spring Boot, everything is set up correctly.

All the templates are in the same folder:

**/resources/templates**

edit:

The main idea is to have one boilerplate html file with all the script tags and link tages, head and body.

This should be the main template with a **$content** variable, this is a placeholder for every other page.

Now every other page should be included into that main page.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> test </title>
</head>
<body>

$content

##the templates you want to 'execute' and render

#parse("example.vm")
#parse("example1.vm")
##...
#parse("example-n.vm")

##The templates you want to 'render' but not 'execute' as velocity templates.

#include("include.vm")
#include("include1.vm")
#include("include2.vm")
##...
#include("include-n.vm")

</body>
</html>
```

This would help...

Please note this:-

- Using the `#parse()` macro would *execute* the template and then include it.
- Using the `#include()` macro would include the template as *plaintext*.

Comment: Yea but this just renders 'example.vm' I'd like to create many templates with different names which should be rendered as content. How could I achieve that? see my edit in question.

Comment: could you please give me an example?